# Samba password expires?

Tags: server, password, samba

I have a problem with samba, I have a user and a password for that user, and from a windows machine it let's me log in but after a few hours I try to log in again and it tells me that the password is wrong; so I reset the same password in the server and it works again; then, after a few hours it tells me it's wrong.... Any ideas what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When you first connect, does it offer you some options?